# playing mp3 from URL is taking too much time

Tags: android, media-player

I am trying to play mp3 from a URL . But Its taking too much time to Play the file online , Due to this user has to wait till progress dialog is dismiss which is a serious issue for me.How can I reduce the time to play music .My URL and Code is :

URL :[http://ice31.securenetsystems.net/STUDIO1?type=.mp3][1]

```
public class Player extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
    private Context context;
    private String stationUrl;
    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    private boolean initialStage = true;
    private boolean playPause;
    public Boolean prepared = false;
    public ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;


    public Player(String stationUrl,Context context) {
        this.stationUrl =  stationUrl;
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        CommonUtils.showProgress(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... strings) {

        try {

            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stationUrl);
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    initialStage = true;
                    playPause = false;
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                    mediaPlayer.reset();
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            prepared = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            prepared = false;
        }

        return prepared;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);
        CommonUtils.dismissProgress();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        if (!CommonUtils.getPreferencesString(context,AppConstants.STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        {
            if (CommonUtils.getPreferencesString(context,AppConstants.STATUS).equalsIgnoreCase("One"))
            {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        }
        initialStage = false;
    }


}
```

Comment: Why do you use it in `AsyncTask<>`?

Answer (score 2):

`MediaPlayer` doesn't work well with audio streams. There is no way to reduce time of MediaPlayer's buffering. From documentation it seems that
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html
is better choice, or even https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaExtractor.html which is more complicated but are better suited for streaming.

Comment: I have overcome this issue by using ExoPlayer. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/exoplayer.html

Comment: with exoplayer can I play from a url faster?